# Timezone independent due date comparison in rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, activerecord, timezone

Consider the following case. I have a **Voucher** model with a datetime **activation_due_date** field and user model that has up-to-date information about his location (timezone, UTC offset).
I want to check if he requests voucher activation before due date **in any of available time zones**. For instance, If a due date is set to 28.08.2018 23:59 UTC
I want my scope before_activation_due to check if he requests something before 28.08.2018 - 23:59 in his current time zone so **my due date is not something fixed** - it depends on users location - In one place it can be after due date and in the other before.
I have tried the following approach.

## models/voucher.rb

```
scope :before_activation_due, lambda { |user|
  where('activation_due_date > ? ', Time.current.to_utc + user.utc_offset)
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a right approach? If not, what is the proper way for dealing with such cases?
2. How to test such a scope? The current timestamp is probably taken from a database server when comparing datetimes during query execution so I am not sure how to mock it in my specs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to convert the `activation_due_date` into the timezone of the user. As you say "my due date is not something fixed - it depends on users location".

To do this as a scope the easiest thing would be to use your databases timezone functions. This depends on which database you are using, but in PostgreSQL it will be something like:-

`where('activation_due_date AT TIME ZONE ? > NOW() ', user.timezone)`

---

An even simpler way would be to do a string comparison

`where('to_char(activation_due_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') > ?', Time.current.in_time_zone(user.timezone).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S');`

In this case we are saying what is the time on the wall for the user, and is it less than time in the database (which is "stored" in UTC).

Answer (score 4):

You can store just the timezone of the user, not the offset, then do:

```
where('activation_due_date > ? ', Time.now.utc.in_time_zone(user.timezone))
```

where timezone is any valid timezone shown in

```
rake time:zones
```

That'd be the more rails-y way to do things at least. But I don't think storing an offset then manually adding it to the time is a bad approach.

To test this, you can manually insert any date you want in to your database. Then you can use a gem like https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop to travel in time to that point, and test your scope:

```
Voucher.create(activation_due_date: '2018-01-02 00:00:00')
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
time = DateTime.strptime("2018-01-02 00:00:00 Central Time (US & Canada)",format)
Timecop.travel(time)
Voucher.before_activation_due.all ...
```